# c++ default parameters value

Tags: c++, default, default-value

I would like to make sure that this method call is correct. I have three arguments, and one defaults to a null QString.

```
double funcApply(double* param, QString expr=NULL);
```

and the call is

```
funcApply(param);
```

In function body, I test whether second argument expr is NULL or not, and proceed accrodingly. Will this call behave as expected, or misbehave?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run it?

Comment: I have errors: 'redefinition of default parameter' and 'ambiguous clal to overload function' at compile time

Comment: @PéterTörök: Running it might not give the correct answer. Maybe the questioner is specifically interested in whether default parameter values for non-POD are valid or yield undefined behavior.

Comment: @phresnel, of course it may not be decisive, but it is important info to be included in the post nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you expect it to behave like.

Technically, `expr` will not be `NULL` since it's not a pointer, but its contents will be empty. (assuming you mean [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html)).

Of course, if you have something like `#define QString char*`, then `expr` will be `NULL`, but I doubt you have that.

Comment: For `QString`s, there is a special mode that you get with constructing it with a null pointer. See [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#distinction-between-null-and-empty-strings).

Comment: @leftaroundabout that's the link I posted. And exactly what I'm saying - but expr is not NULL. It can't be since it's not a pointer.

Comment: Yeah, but a null string is not the same thing as an empty string, that's my point. (I edited the link to the section).

Comment: ok, then it will work is have have default QString expr = QString::number(0) and test whether expr equals QString::number(0)? I don't care the value of expr if this is not user given, I only want to be able to test the value one way or another.

Comment: @dlib or you can default to `QString expr = QString()` and test it with `isNull`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have errors 'redefinition of default parameter' and 'ambiguous call to overloaded function' at compile time

For some reason, you are not allowed to repeat a default argument once it is given. If you have the default value in your header file, like:

```
double funcApply(double* param, QString expr=NULL);
```

the implementation must not repeat it, but be something like

```
double funcApply(double* param, QString expr /*=NULL*/)
{
    // do something
}
```

If you actually test the `expr` parameter for `NULL` and do two different things, you might be better off with two separate functions that do these "different things"

```
 double funcApply(double* param);
 double funcApply(double* param, QString expr);
```

and avoid this problem.